# What is the value of $N$ in a three-digit number $1N1$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I don't know how to solve this problem. This is as far as I can go.
$$\frac{1N1}{N}=2N+5$$
 Then what should I do from there? Any help is highly appreciated.

> If a three-digit number of the form $1N1$ is divided by N, the quotient is of the form $2N$ remainder $5$. What is the value of $N$?

Comment: There are only $9$ possibilities, so anything other than trial and error would seem to be overthinking the problem.

Comment: Should $2N$ be considered twice $N$, or a two-digit number with leading tens place $2$?

Comment: @hardmath Trial and error shows that there is a solution for the second option but not the first.

Comment: Note that the written (highlighted) version of your problem does not correspond to your equation.

Comment: @Joffan There's no reason $N$ cannot be even .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that the OP's equation is wrong. The correct equation is
$1N1=N(2N)+5$ corresponding to the boxed problem.

We rewrite the equation in variables rather than place-value notation.
$1N1=100+10N+1$, and $2N=20+N$.

Now we substitute and solve:
$$100+10N+1 = (N+20)N+5,$$ or $$0=N^2+10N-96=(N+16)(N-6).$$

Then $N=6$, since it cannot be $-16$.

We check:
$161=6(26)+5$

As for why the original equation must be wrong, we would have $101+10N = N(aN+b)$ for either $a=2$, $b=5$, or $a=1$, $b=25$ depending on how one interprets the $2N$. But by the rational root theorem, the integer roots have to divide 101. Since 101 is prime, that would mean the root would have to be 1, which is impossible since the left hand side is a three digit number, and the right hand side would be at most two digits.

Comment: @Joffan I believe the OP's question is poorly expressed.  Jgon's solution works for the written (highlighted) version.

Comment: OK got it - well done for reading it properly :-)